# How to access the volume in host in docker for windows

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run the docker for Windows and ubuntu in WSL.
When I run the following command

`docker volume create test`
`docker volume inspect test`

I get the following output

```
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/test/_data",
        "Name": "test",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

when I access the location, I get
`bash: cd: /var/lib/docker/volumes: No such file or directory`

So how should I access the folder?

Answer (score 3):

The directory is is protected so you can `cd` into it, however you can `ls` the contents:

```
sudo ls /wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes/test/_data
```

I've modified my WSL set up as per [this article](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#ensure-volume-mounts-work) so you may find your path is different.  I think the default path is probably `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes/test/_data`

You might find it more useful to mount a directory in your Windows user folder which can be done by changing the WSL mount point as per the article linked to above and then running:

```
docker volume create --driver local --name test --opt device=/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/<username>/test --opt type=none --opt o=bind
```

(assuming you've got a folder called `test` at the root of your Windows user directory)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these path exist on my machine (i used the same article to set it up). But using a custom folder i have been sucessful.

Answer (score 2):

based on [@nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7360635/nick-graham) answer

- From linux: `sudo ls /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes`
- From windows: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`

Answer (score 0):

For me the volumes data are at `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data/community/docker/volumes`, each distro may mount `wsl` at different location, this is the default path for Ubuntu at least.

I can `cd` into it with `root` permission.